# lsp pyright cannot recognize pyenv virtualenv python interpreter

Tags: python, virtualenv, neovim, pyenv, pyright

I use nvim and Mason to manage the lsp server pyright.
and just set pyright.setup{} and don't set any options.

```
local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")
lspconfig.pyright.setup{}
```

Because I usually switch python2 and python3, I install pyenv to manage python versions.
I found use `pyenv local` command cannot make pyright recognize the correct python.
Then I saw the issue https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/issues/717.
It said local file cannot be recognized is normal, but `pyenv shell` and `pyenv activate` should be recognize.

But for me, both of two ways cannot work.

`my-python2` created by `pyenv virtualenv 2.7.18 my-python2` command

[image]

[image]

using `print a` still reporting an error. And using `pyenv activate` is the same error

```
echo $PATH

/Users/xxxx/.pyenv/shims:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
```

So I want to know why cannot work fine like the git issue.
And how I can work fine when I exec `pyenv shell` or `pyenv activate`